# Java API For reading .numbers files for MAC

Tags: java, macos, numbers

My requirement is to read numbers(*Iwork Files in MAC OS*) format files. I want to do this task in java. Is there any available API in java?

Comment: For others who don’t know the .numbers file format: [link](http://file.org/extension/numbers). @bHDave, I’d be surprised if a library for this purpose exists, but you can never tell. Did you search the web already? Did you check whether Apache POI can do this stuff (just a wild guess)?

Comment: Thanks for hint. I already searched in web.For apache POI.. I will check it out and update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org) which has a class, specifically `org.apache.tika.parser.iwork.IWorkPackageParser`, to extract text and metadata from `.numbers` files.

Comment: Thanks Matteo Baldi, I tried IWorkPackageParser but it is only supporting lower version of .Numbers file.  it has comment written "Numbers format version 1.x. Currently only tested with Numbers version 2.0.x". even after exporting to lower version of numbers. it is not working as expected.

Comment: @bHDave Did you ever find something suitable?